# roslaunch to launch python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to add following to roslaunch?

```
roscd <package>
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262321/roslaunch-to-launch-python-simplehttpserver/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes: create a small wrapper bash script that does `roscd <package>` first, then runs `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

Easiest is to add this to a package, then use regular `node type=".." pkg=".." name=".."` syntax to start it.

Personally I try to keep any ROS-isms out of such files, by passing the output of `$(find package)` (an absolute path) as the first argument to the script (and then do a `cd $x` (where `x` is the correct argument nr) in the script, but make sure to take ROS args into account).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0